# Getting the hang of Kotlin Delegates

Tags: kotlin, delegates, delegation

I'm struggling to wrap my head around Kotlin delegates.  I'm finding it especially tricky when it comes to using it with **generics**.  In my case, I want a delegate where I can store a value of arbitrary type.  The first time I access the delegated property it returns the stored value.  All subsequent accesses just return `null`.  If I set the value again then the next access will return the value and all following access operations will once-again return `null`.  It would work like this:

```
val a: Int by AccessOnce() // or String, or Boolean, or whatever
println(a) // null
a = 42
println(a) // 42
println(a) // null

a = 100
println(a) // 100
println(a) // null
```

This is the code I have so far, but it's not happy with the `getValue` and `setValue` signatures.  Could you help me out?

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class AccessOnce <T> {
    var storedValue: T? = null
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: T?, property: KProperty<*>): T? {
        val retVal =  storedValue
        storedValue = null
        return retVal
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T?) {
        storedValue = value
    }

}
```

Comment: You can implement [`ReadWriteProperty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-read-write-property/) interface to make sure your delegate's object have the right signatures.

Comment: Ok, cool, But I'm confused about `R - the type of object which owns the delegated property`.  What does that mean?

Comment: `ReadWriteProperty` is an interface, so inside `getValue` function `this` is  (in your case) AccessOnce class. But you use `val a: Int by AccessOnce()` inside others class. `R` must be the type (or supertype) of the object which owns `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is you are conflating the types of `thisRef` and of the property itself. `thisRef` is whatever object has the property that is being delegated. In most cases, you will just make it of type `Any` so your delegate can be used in any class you like. But if you had a special type of delegate that only works for a certain type of class, you could use that type for `thisRef` and then in the operator functions you could have your getter and/or setter call other functions on the class or do other work.

So to fix yours, you just need to change `thisRef` to an `Any`.

```
class AccessOnce <T> {
    var storedValue: T? = null
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T? {
        val retVal =  storedValue
        storedValue = null
        return retVal
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T?) {
        storedValue = value
    }

}
```

Incidentally, `getValue` could be a one-liner:

```
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T? =
         storedValue.also { storedValue = null }
```